# Need to fixed the position of anything wrapped with React Component

Tags: html, reactjs, sass

I made a React Component below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5LIu.png)

I Need to make MakeFixed Component like if i wrapped anything inside it that will fixed on its placed to go on top or anything.

Comment: Add more description and your code in the post

Comment: like this?function MakeFixed({children}){
  return <div style={{position:'fixed'}}>
    {children}
  </div>
}